# psr-4 class not found

Tags: php, psr-4

I'm trying to setup my first project with psr-4 but I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'leaseregistratie\Repositories'
> not found in /home/vagrant/Code/testomgeving/index.php:7 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/Code/testomgeving/index.php on line 7

My folder structure:

```
testomgeving has (psr4,composer.json,index.php,vendor)
psr4 (start.php)
app 
leaseregistratie 
Repositories (UserRepository.php)
```

index.php:

```
<?php

use leaseregistratie\Repositories\UserRepository as user;

require_once 'psr4/start.php';

$user = new user();

?>
```

start.php:

```
<?php

require_once '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

UserRepository:

```
<?php

namespace leaseregistratie\Repositories;

class UserRepository {

    public function __construct()
    {
        die('user!');
    }

}
```

Composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
         "psr-4": {
            "leaseregistratie\\": "app/leaseregistratie"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you do composer dump-autoload ??

Comment: you need to move require_once 'psr4/start.php'; above the use statement, because at the moment it tries to load the class before loading the autoloader

Comment: @Drudge yes I've done that.

Comment: @MichailStrokin still the error! Also when I do $user = new leaseregistratie\Repositories\UserRepository();

Comment: could you add die('test') to the autoload.php to see if it gets loaded? if not,  remove first slash in the start.php

Comment: @MichailStrokin yes It's loaded!

Comment: do you have leaseregistratie folder inside the app folder? or does it sit in webroot? (composer.json tells us that it's should be in app folder)

Comment: @MichailStrokin yes it's in the app folder.